# Testing form reset on Vue with Jest

Tags: javascript, vue.js, unit-testing, jestjs, vue-test-utils

Testing a form built with Vue using Jest for unit tests. Among the elements I have a reset button (type=reset), which works fine and once clicked it removes all the values already introduced.

However, when unit testing, the button click doesn't seem to clear the values. I don't have a handler for the click, just using the default reset function of the form.

I've also tried using `wrapper.emmited('reset');` to no avail, and `wrapper.emmitedByOrder();` returns an empty array.

How do I test that the reset button is generated correctly and works as expected?

```
test('Assert Form Components', async () => {
 const wrapper = mount(FormElement, {
            propsData: {
                message: sampleJSON.formJSON
            }
        })

let resetBtn = wrapper.find('.form-reset');
let requiredInput = wrapper.find('.required-input');
....
requiredInput.setValue('test');
expect(requiredInput.element).toHaveValue('test'); //This passes

await resetBtn.trigger('click');
expect(requiredInput.element).not.toHaveValue('test') //This fails
....
```

Comment: You may need to put a `await wrapper.vm.$nextTick()` after the `await resetBtn.trigger('click');` to let the dom settle.

Comment: I created a vue jest template on codepen, perhaps you can try reproducing the issue there and I can then try to fix it. https://codepen.io/AlgeoMA/pen/vYmdWVa

Comment: @AlexMA Your suggestion to wait for the next tick worked, thanks!

Comment: It trips up a lot of developers. The concept of an async digest cycle, while great for performance, makes unit testing dom manipulation sort of painful sometimes. I’m surprised you had to attach to document. Be warned that when you do that you must destroy the wrapper manually or the test may leak state into other tests.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently there were two things missing. First, as @AlexMA suggested, allowing for another tick to let the DOM settle. Second, I needed to attach the wrapper to the DOM. The final code look something like this:

```
test('Assert Form Components', async () => {
 const wrapper = mount(FormElement, {
            propsData: {
                message: sampleJSON.formJSON
            },
            attachTo: document.body
        })

let resetBtn = wrapper.find('.form-reset');
let requiredInput = wrapper.find('.required-input');
....
requiredInput.setValue('test');
expect(requiredInput.element).toHaveValue('test'); //This passes

await resetBtn.trigger('click');
await wrapper.vm.$nextTick()
expect(requiredInput.element).not.toHaveValue('test') //This works now!
....
```